# Код для вписывания номера в поле

Tags: java, парсер, пароль, ввод

Очень странный заголовок, но все же. Java только учу. В общем, есть у нас вай фай вход в который через ID. Пароли у всех одинаковые. Вход происходит в браузере. Все ID знаю, но постоянно вводить их не круто и долго, да и заняты бывают. Как написать программу, которая вписывает в окно входа ID, а в окно пароля пароли. (IDшники можно просто через for сделать, они примерно такие 855XXXXX). Подскажите, комрады.

Comment: Добавте в вопрос ваш код, а то смысл задачи не совсем понятен.

Comment: [Напишите минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) того что вы конкретно пытаетесь сделать,

Comment: Наверное, вам поможет `Robot` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html), но да, не помешает ваш код.

Answer (score 0):

Это сложная задача. Есть 3 подхода к снаряду:

1) Написать костыли заполнять через JavaScript в `WebView`:

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('username').value = '"+username+"';");
```

2) Написать собственную клавиатуру и заполнять через нее - точно не скажу как, но видел как это работает (см. например [Keeper Password Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.callpod.android_apps.keeper&hl=ru) )

3) Использовать Android [Autofill API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill.html)

Возможно есть и другие способы.